# Which loan type is cheapest?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I have a 4% loan that spans 20 years, where I pay a fixed amount every three months.

If I make an extra payment, I then can choose between two options

- keep the duration of the loan constant, and I pay less every 3 months

or

- the duration of the loan is shortened and I pay the same amount every 3 months that I always have.

**Question**

How do I calculate which option that is the over all cheapest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option will be cheaper in terms of interest paid, as you have money borrowed for less time.  You can check this by making a spreadsheet and doing the amortization table.  Each three months, you add 1% interest then deduct the payment.  Excel (and I believe other spreadsheets) has a PMT function that will find the new payment on the loan so it comes out even.